# Can I convert a string to a variable name and use it?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
int P1=400
int P2=350
int P3=204
int P4=235
```

And then, I want to use this variable in the following form:

```
for (int i=1; i<=4; i++){
  for (int j=1; j<=4; j++){
  }
}
```

In the `for` loop, I want to compare two variables **based on the value of `i` and `j`**, such as if `i` is 1 and `j` is 3, I want to compare P1 and P3, is this possible?

Comment: Not possible in the way you asked. Variable names don't even exist at runtime, they are just memory locations. But it sounds like an array or vector will do what you need.

Comment: There are no strings in the code that you have provided, so the question is unclear and should be reworded.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, and will take more work and effort than another method.  First, create a table or use `std::map`, to associate a name (string) to the address of a variable, e.g. `std::map<string, int *>`.  You will have to build a string with the name of the variable.  I recommend using `std::ostringstream`.  Next, use the string with the map to get the address of the variable.  Dereference the pointer to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

The actual names of the variables are not available at runtime in a programmatic way (C++ does not have support for reflection in any meaningful way at this time). However, it looks like your variables are some name + a number, which often means that an array or vector would be a better choice. If that is the case, you can certainly manually input the common name as in

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> p = {400, 350, 204, 235};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            const char* cmp = p[i] < p[j] ? "less than" : "greater or equal to";
            std::cout << "p[" << i << "] is " << cmp << " p[" << j << "]\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p[0] is greater or equal to p[0]
p[0] is greater or equal to p[1]
p[0] is greater or equal to p[2]
p[0] is greater or equal to p[3]
p[1] is less than p[0]
p[1] is greater or equal to p[1]
p[1] is greater or equal to p[2]
p[1] is greater or equal to p[3]
p[2] is less than p[0]
p[2] is less than p[1]
p[2] is greater or equal to p[2]
p[2] is less than p[3]
p[3] is less than p[0]
p[3] is less than p[1]
p[3] is greater or equal to p[2]
p[3] is greater or equal to p[3]
```

Comment: A simple array would have sufficed in this case, I think. Also, to extend this answer, it'd make sense also to use a map in the case where it isn't just integers. Like a string map or something, if it's really needed to access something "by name".